# My Vinca plants are dying

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, flowers, plant-recommendations, wilt

My Vinca plants are dying in my pots at home. Please suggest some measures to prevent further or possible cause for it.

[image: Plant pic]

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfoUi.jpg]

Comment: I can't tell the size of the pot, especially how deep the pot is, nor if it is standing inside something - does the pot have drainage holes, is there a tray a the bottom and how long has the plant been in that pot and what size is the pot?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like annual vinca, a frost sensitive short lived plant. Did you over winter it indoors? Or plant it fresh this spring? Annual vinca needs full sun, 6 hours, and maybe a bigger pot. I would cut back the dead foliage. Is this inside? Need more information.